Why is my .mp4 file created using cv2.VideoWriter not syncing up with the audio when i combine the video and audio using ffmpeg
The aim of the script is to take text from a text file and put it onto a stock video with an ai reading the text. Similar to those reddit stories on social media with parkour minecraft in the background.
import cv2
import time
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer
from Transcription import newTranscribeAudio
from pydub import AudioSegment

#get a gpt text generation to create a story based on a prompt, for example sci-fi story and spread it over 3-4 parts
#get stock footage, like minecraft parkour etc
#write text of script on the footage
#create video for each part
#have ai voiceover to read the transcript
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("Stock_Videos\Minecraft_Parkour.mp4")
transcription = newTranscribeAudio("final_us.wav")
player = MediaPlayer("final_us.mp3")
audio = AudioSegment.from_file("final_us.mp3")
story = open("Story.txt", "r").read()
story_split = story.split("||")
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
frame_count = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
video_duration = frame_count / fps  # Duration of one loop of the video
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
audio_duration = len(audio) / 1000  # Duration in seconds
video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(f"CompletedVideo.mp4", fourcc, fps, (1080, 1920))

choice = 0#part of the story choice
part_split = story_split[choice].split(" ")
with open("Segment.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(story_split[choice])
start_time = time.time()
length = len(part_split) - 1
next_text = []
for j in range(0, length):
    temp = part_split[j].replace("\n", "")
    next_text.append([temp])
index = 0
word_index = 0
frame_size_x = 1080
frame_size_y = 1920
audio_duration = len(audio) / 1000  # Duration in seconds
start_time = time.time()
wait_time = 1 / fps
while (time.time() - start_time) < audio_duration:
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0)  # Restart video
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(video_writer)
    if index >= len(transcription):
        break
    while cap.isOpened():
        # Capture frames in the video 
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        audio_frame, val = player.get_frame()
        if val == 'eof':  # End of file
            print("Audio playback finished.")
            break
        if index >= len(transcription):
            break
        
        if frame_size_x == -1:
            frame_size_x = frame.shape[1]
            frame_size_y = frame.shape[0]

        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

        # describe the type of font 
        # to be used. 
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX 
        trans = transcription[index]["words"]
        end_time = trans[word_index]["end"]
        if trans[word_index]["start"] < elapsed_time < trans[word_index]["end"]:
            video_text = trans[word_index]["text"]
        elif elapsed_time >= trans[word_index]["end"]:
            #index += 1
            word_index += 1
        if (word_index >= len(trans)):
            index += 1
            word_index = 0
        # get boundary of this text
        textsize = cv2.getTextSize(video_text, font, 3, 6)[0]
        # get coords based on boundary
        textX = int((frame.shape[1] - textsize[0]) / 2)
        textY = int((frame.shape[0] + textsize[1]) / 2)
        
        cv2.putText(frame,  
                    video_text,  
                    (textX, textY),  
                    font, 3,  
                    (0, 255, 255),  
                    6,  
                    cv2.LINE_4)
        
        # Define the resize scale
        scale_percent = 50  # Resize to 50% of the original size
        # Get new dimensions
        width = 1080
        height = 1920
        new_size = (width, height)

        # Resize the frame
        resized_frame = cv2.resize(frame, new_size)
        video_writer.write(resized_frame)
        cv2.imshow('video', resized_frame)
        cv2.waitKey(wait_time)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
            break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video_writer.release()
cap.release()


When I run this script the audio matches the text in the video perfectly and it runs for the correct amount of time to match with the audio (2 min 44 sec). However, the saved video CompletedVideo.mp4 only lasts for 1 min 10 sec. I am unsure why the video has sped up. The fps is 60 fps. If you require any more information please let me know and thanks in advance.
I have tried changing the fps, changing the wait_time after writing each frame. I am expecting the CompletedVideo.mp4 to be 2 min 44 sec long not 1 min 10 sec long.

How many output video frames do you have? 9840 or 4200? Better yet, could you post the video file information (both input & output)?

For what it's worth, if I were to do something like this, I'd either make my Python script to generate an FFMpeg filtergraph script (repeated drawtext) or a subtitle file (WebVTT maybe?) then call FFmpeg to merge video/audio/subtitle streams together...

the fps is a lie. that's my bet. -- don't rely on ffpyplayer or OpenCV to get video timing right. use PyAV. or do it all with ffmpeg CLI, if possible.

[mre] required. your code surely can be lightened and stripped, right? and you need to supply the input data that it requires. then we can hope to replicate your issue.

if this question is about imshow() and waitKey()... then you're asking entirely the wrong thing. those are not for 1:1 exact timing of video playback. those are for prototyping. those don't reflect on any video written with cv.VideoWriter
